# If, else, elsif, else if to only show object when not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on Rails application, I have a "Bootstrap" row of images with hyperlinks. I want to only show the ones that have content in them.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="span3">
    <h5 class="pagination-centered">
        <%= link_to (image_tag "/img/folder.jpg", alt: "Buyer's Guides", width: "75px"), action: "index", filter: @filter, type: "buyers_guides" %>
        <%= link_to "Buyer's Guides", action: "index", filter: @filter, type: "buyers_guides" %>
    </h5>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <h5 class="pagination-centered">
        <%= link_to (image_tag "/img/folder.jpg", alt: "Datasheets", width: "75px"), action: "index", filter: @filter, type: "datasheets" %>
        <%= link_to "Datasheets", action: "index", filter: @filter, type: "datasheets" %>
    </h5>
</div>
```

Would using an if else statement be okay? Else if, elsif?

Or what about the controller?

```
class Users::MarketingController < ApplicationController
def index
    @filter = params[:filter]
    @type = params[:type]

if @filter
        if @type    
        arrays_of_strings_to_check_against = ['logos', 'datasheets', 'buyers_guides', 'videos', 'web_banners', 'presentations', 'documents', 'press_releases' ]

        if arrays_of_strings_to_check_against.any?{ |o| @type =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(o)}\b/ }
            base_dir = "public/files/marketing"
            @files = Dir.glob("#{base_dir}/voip/#{@filter}/#{@type.downcase}/*.[a-z]*")
            @view = "files"
        else    
            @view = 'types'
        end
    else
        @view = 'types'
    end
else
    @view = "category"
end
end
```

end

New to this and trying to learn good practices.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `if`/`else` is used typically in this scenario, though definitely ugly. You can also use the `condition ? do_if_true : do_if_false` notation, which is convenient here.

```
<% if has_content_condition %>
 <div class="span3">
  <h5 class="pagination-centered">
    <%= link_to (image_tag "/img/folder.jpg", alt: "Buyer's Guides", width: "75px"), action: "index", filter: @filter, type: "buyers_guides" %>
    <%= link_to "Buyer's Guides", action: "index", filter: @filter, type: "buyers_guides" %>
  </h5>
 </div>
 <div class="span3">
  <h5 class="pagination-centered">
    <%= link_to (image_tag "/img/folder.jpg", alt: "Datasheets", width: "75px"), action: "index", filter: @filter, type: "datasheets" %>
    <%= link_to "Datasheets", action: "index", filter: @filter, type: "datasheets" %>
  </h5>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

I don't know for sure if this is what you had in mind. If not clear, comment, and I'll be happy to help. =)

Comment: Ugly, but can be quicker to parse when reading over old code.

Comment: What about a @filter in the controller?

Comment: You could do `<% if @filter %>`. Is that what you mean? (Or at least you used to be able to do this in Rails 2, but it's been a while for me.)

Comment: Okay, I will play around with if @filter and if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could also do this:

```
if x.present?
  x
end
```

So for example

```
@image = image.find(params[:id])
if @image.present?
  <div class="span3">
    <h5 class="pagination-centered">
      <%= link_to (image_tag "/img/folder.jpg", alt: "Buyer's Guides", width: "75px"), action: "index", filter: @filter, type: "buyers_guides" %>
      <%= link_to "Buyer's Guides", action: "index", filter: @filter, type: "buyers_guides" %>
    </h5>
  </div>
end
```